# Automatic math equation generator not displaying correctly

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a program what generates math problems. Each problem should have the following format:

```
<num> <op> <num>  = ?
```

Where each num represents a random number between -50 and 50 and op is randomly selected from the four basic math operators: +, -, /, *.

So far I have:

```
import random
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

def main(): 

    random.seed()

    ops = (add, sub, mul, truediv)
    op = random.choice(ops)

    num1 = random.randint(-50,50)
    num2 = random.randint(-50,50)    

    answer = op(num1, num2)
    answer = round(answer,2)   
    print("Welcome! Here is your practice problem:\n")

    print(num1, op ,num2,"=?\n")
main(
```

But when I compile it, it comes back with, for example:

```
-2 <built-in function truediv> -27 =?
```

Instead of:
    -2 / -27 =?

How can I get it so it displays the operator instead of

```
<built-in function truediv>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a dict `opsStr = {add :'+', sub: '-', ...}` and print its corresponding entry for the selected operator.

So your print would look like:

```
print(num1, opsStr [op] ,num2,"=?\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking it up.

```
op_display = {
   add: '+',
   sub: '-',
   mult: '*',
   truediv: '/',
}
print(num1, op_display[op], num2,"=?\n")
```

Alternately you could use `op.__name__` to give something more presentable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
ops = [(add,'+'), (sub, '-'), (mul, '*'), (truediv, '/')]
op, symbol = random.choice(ops)
```

Then you print the symbol.

Note that ops should really be a global constant

Comment: A global constant? Please explain.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, what do you need explained? Surely you know how to create a global constant...

Comment: Actually I didn't even know that python had constants. And why does it have to be global? IMHO one should avoid globals unless there is no other way. How do you create a global constant? Wrapped inside a class with overridden __setattr__?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, it's true that python doesn't have constants like some other languages. But you can create a variable that you don't modify after assigning it, and that's typically called a constant. See for example, PEP 8, which discusses naming convention for them. I agree that global *variables* should be avoided, but there isn't anything wrong with global *constants*.